# EK-TM4C1294XL uart speed support

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, microchip, texas-instruments

I am starting a project as part of my Electrical engineering b.sc

I try to find if the following Evolution kit support UART with the following speeds:
600, 1200, 3400, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 38400, 56000, 57600, 115200, 128000, 256000, 460800, 921600

The kit is :
EK-TM4C1294XL
[link to product](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-tm4c1294xl#descriptionArea)

I tried to find if I would be able to use this micro chip with those speeds

Thanks guys

Comment: Yes. All of the above and anything inbetween.

Comment: Where i can verify it?

Comment: Will it be possible to listen for 2 uart inputs at the maximum from the list?

Comment: @user2027090 You verify things like these by reading the documentation for the chip (and board), unless you have the hardware and can try it out yourself, of course.

Comment: @user2027090 Modified answer below.

Comment: This isn't even a question, is it? What does this have to do with C?

Comment: You write the code in c in the microchip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To program an integral UART you usually configure a clock divisor rather than a specific baud rate. See the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c1294ncpdt.pdf) on the processor page 1165.

"Will it be possible to listen for 2 uart inputs at the maximum from the list?"

The 8 UARTS run independently. Whether you can process the received data without buffer overflow, depends on how slickly you write the code. You need to do some maths based on BAUD rate and CPU instruction execution times.

Comment: but if the code is average it will be possible at 2 uart at 460800 baud to transfer via pc as binary(no parsing)just transfering

Comment: Will the interuppts will not overide themselvs so ill lose data or the spec is enougth ?

Comment: As I said, you'll need to assess that yourself. Do you intend writing the UART handling code or using a supplied library function? I don't know the interrupt specifics of this processor, but typically you must not re-enable interrupts before you have cleared the IRQ flag from the UART that caused the present interrupt (which you usually do by reading the RXD register). Your handling time must also include the interrupt latency, ie how long to push regs and start servicing your code.

Comment: If you are using 1 start bit, 8 data bits and 1 stop bit you have 10 bit times to service the input before another is ready, otherwise it's buffer overrun. You might need to write your own handler since library routines are often inefficient. As there are 8 UARTs you  might need to hard code the register addresses rather than use a single general purpose library function. Use the library to get you going - develop step by step.